# Check and Uncheck Checkbox Dynamically with jQuery : bug?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I made a script in order to control master & slave checkboxes (automatic checking and unchecking).

Here is my JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myCheck').click(function() {
        $('.myCheck').attr('checked', false);
    });
    $('.myCheck').click(function() {
        if ($('.myCheck').is(':checked')) {
            $('#myCheck').attr('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('#myCheck').attr('checked', true); // IT DOESN'T WORK, WHY ?
            alert("Checkbox Master must be checked, but it's not!");
        }
    });

});
```

And here is my HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" checked="checked" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Checkbox Master<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" value="1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Checkbox Slave 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" value="1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Checkbox Slave 2
```

Look at my simple [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQfMs/) to understand the problem.

**EDIT 1 :** Like Inser said, the problem happens with jQuery 1.9.2 and over. No more problem with jQuery 1.8.3. Strange...

**EDIT 2 :** Inser found the solution, use **.prop('checked', true)** instead **.attr('checked', true)**. Look at the comments below...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `Looking at your simple JsFiddle to understand the problem` but myaaan!! i cannot figure what are you trying to do...so what you want acctully

Comment: Ok, sorry guys I thought my code was clear... In fact, once you click the Checkbox Master, all Checkboxes Slave must be unchecked : it's working fine. In the other hand, once you uncheck a Checkbox Slave and there is no other checked Checkbox Slave, Checkbox Master must be checked automatically. Sorry for that, I hope you'll understand my problem now...

Comment: Looks like it's jquery issue. It works perfectly in version 1.8.3, but does not after 1.9.1

Comment: Damned, you're right Inser! So it's a real Jquery bug...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use prop method for new versions of jQuery:

```
$('#myCheck').prop('checked', true);
$('#myCheck').prop('checked', false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uQfMs/37/

Comment: Thanks a lot Inser, this is the solution, you saved my day (and night)! Well done! ;-)

Comment: really nice, I was getting crazy with lastest jquery 1.11, thank you!

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in jquery version 2+... or is it just me?

Answer (score 3):

You could try this.

```
$('#myCheck').click(function() {
    var checkBoxes = $(this).siblings('input[type=checkbox]');
    checkBoxes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false);
});
```

Comment: The ternary operator is redundant.  `$(this).is(':checked') ? true : false` will always return the same boolean value as `$(this).is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want to check the master checkbox:

```
$('#myCheck').click(function() {
       $('.myCheck').attr('checked', false);
       $(this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQfMs/7/).

Answer (score 0):

i made some experiences , actually 
`$(':checkbox').attr('checked',false);` althought this could set the "checked" attribute , but it won't continuesly shows in the visual . and `$(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);` this one works perfectly! hope this could do some help .

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you a plugin for this:

```
$.fn.dependantCheckbox = function() {
  var $targ = $(this);
  function syncSelection(group, action) {
    $targ.each(function() {
      if ($(this).data('checkbox-group') === group) {
        $(this).prop('checked', action);
      }
    });
  };
  $('input[type="checkbox"][data-checkbox-group]').on('change', function() {
    var groupSelection = $(this).data('checkbox-group');
    var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    syncSelection(groupSelection, isChecked);
  });
}
$('input[type="checkbox"][data-checkbox-group]').dependantCheckbox();


<input data-checkbox-group="1" type="checkbox" id="test" />
<label for="test">test</label>
<input data-checkbox-group="1" type="checkbox" id="test2" />
<label for="test2">test2</label>
<input data-checkbox-group="2" type="checkbox" id="test3" />
<label for="test3">test3</label>
<input data-checkbox-group="2" type="checkbox" id="test4" />
<label for="test4">test4</label>
```

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/mJqyqG

Comment: really nice plugin. Just wanted to know if an input box is a part of more than one groups then how this can be handled as per this plugin?