# Check and Uncheck Checkbox Dynamically with jQuery : bug? II

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, checkbox

I want to use the same functionality as described at [Check and Uncheck Checkbox Dynamically with jQuery : bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474759/check-and-uncheck-checkbox-dynamically-with-jquery-bug) - i.e. one master checkbox and two slaves checkboxes.

The difference compared to the previous question is that I need to declare all the checkboxes as button() (as contained here: http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox ):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#myCheck" ).button();
    $( "#myCheck2" ).button();
    $( "#myCheck3" ).button();

    $('#myCheck').click(function() {
        $('.myCheck').prop('checked', false);
    });

    $('.myCheck').click(function() {
        if ($('.myCheck').is(':checked')) {
            $('#myCheck').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('#myCheck').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });

});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/uQfMs/90/

The outcome of this difference is that the functionality is away. I cannot find why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myCheck,#myCheck2,#myCheck3").button();
    $('#myCheck').click(function () {
        $('.myCheck').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
        $("#myCheck,#myCheck2,#myCheck3").button('refresh');
    });
    $('.myCheck').click(function () {
        if ($('.myCheck:checked').length === $('.myCheck').length) $('#myCheck').prop('checked', true);
        if ($('.myCheck:checked').length < $('.myCheck').length) $('#myCheck').prop('checked', false);
        $("#myCheck,#myCheck2,#myCheck3").button('refresh');
    });
    $('#myCheck').click();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uQfMs/103/)** (I added the CSS so you can see the checkboxes changing)

Answer (score 0):

Changes to the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myCheck").click(function () {
        if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('.myCheck').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
            });
        }
    });

    $('.myCheck').click(function () {
        if (!$("#myCheck").prop('checked')) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQfMs/90/)**